# Using browser to find the javascript code currently running

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, firefox

Is it possible to find the javascript code for current event using the console, on any browser?

For example, please see [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nithingm/xogzvsjf/1/). This is the corresponding code:

```
  .close-icon {
    border:1px solid transparent;
    background-color: transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.close-icon:after {
    content: "X";
    display: block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    /*position: absolute;*/
    float:right;
    background-color: #FA9595;
    z-index:1;
    right: 35px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 12px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px #E50F0F;
    cursor: pointer;
}



<input type="range" min="12" max="120" id="slider" />
<div class="text"  contenteditable="true"  style="cursor:grab;">hello1<button class="close-icon dbutton" type="reset"/></div>
<div class="text text1"  contenteditable="true" style="cursor:grab;">hello2<button class="close-icon dbutton1" type="reset"/></div>
<div class="text text2"  contenteditable="true"  style="cursor:grab;">hello3<button class="close-icon dbutton2" type="reset"/></div>
<div class="text text3"  contenteditable="true"  style="cursor:grab;">hello4<button class="close-icon dbutton3" type="reset"/></div>

$("#slider").on("change",function(){
   var v=$(this).val();
   $('.text.active').css('font-size', v + 'px');
});

$('.text').on('focus',function(){
    $('.text').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});

$(document).on("click",".close-icon",function(){

$(this).closest('div').remove();
//alert('hiii');

});
```

Here I write the code to enlarge the text and close the `div`. Now is it possible to see the code responsible for resizing the text, when I am resizing the that text?

> UPDATE : I know how to inspect element, change style and other things
>   . But here i am asking to know how to detect the javascript code or
>   function for the current event.Hi, it's not about console .log
>   function . I know this already . I am asking that how to know which
>   function is working when i click the close button , how can i see that
>   code in browser . Here i write the code , i understand where the code
>   is . What about if some other write the code and  i am looking browser
>   for detecting what code and what event is running

Comment: Did you mean this https://jsfiddle.net/xogzvsjf/2/

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/add-breakpoints : Scroll to setting a DOM Breakpoint

Comment: firebug plugin and use breakpoints

Answer (score 1):

You can run the `console.log()` function on the browser console in situations where it could return useful info for debugging. For example, if you add, on your script, `console.log()` as:

```
$("#slider").on("change",function(){
    var v=$(this).val();
    console.log(v);
    ...
});
```

Then open it in the browser and activate the inspector (`shift + cmd + i` on Chrome on the Mac, for example), and click on the `Console` tab: you should see the value of `v` changing.

Checking which code is responsible for specific tasks may be tricky. One way you can try is to, using Chrome, open the `Console`, click on the `Sources` tab, and click on the little pause icon (pause script execution). Then, when any `javascript` tries to run, Chrome will pause and show you the code. The problem with this approach is that many times there is a loop running constantly. And if that's the case, as soon as you press pause, Chrome will show you the line of `javascript` of that loop, and you won't have time to actually execute the action you're interested at finding the code for.

If you have an idea of which script is running, you can click the `Sources` tab, browse to the `javascript` file that has the code, and add a `breakpoint`. Then you can execute the action, and if the action involves that piece of code, Chrome will pause at that `breakpoint`. In the same tab (`Sources`), try to click the line number, and set "Never pause here". Even though this method won't help you out with every possible code you may be inspecting, sometimes it will.

Also on Chrome, use the console search (open console then `cmd + alt + f` on Chrome for Mac) to search through all the resources loaded on that page. If you know you're looking for a script that deals with a certain `CSS` class or id, you can search for this id or class, see if you can find it on a `javascript` resource, and add a `breakpoint`. When you get to that point, the script will pause, and you will be able to run commands on the console. If your break point was, say, in a class method, then you would be in the scope of that class method context.

Comment: Hi, it's not about console .log function . I know this already . I am asking that how to know which function is working when i click the close button , how can i see that code in browser . Here i write the code , i understand where the code is . What about if some other write the code and  i am looking browser for detecting what code and what event is running

Comment: I added some more ideas to my answer. Does it help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Inspect Element on Chrome by right click to see your code. Select source tab from the inspect window. Same way in Firefox too. Place a break in corresponding event. Using Firebug in Firefox will be better.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: examples attached.

To open DevTools hit `Ctrl + Shift + I` on windows then tab `Console` use examples below:

```
console.log("test");//add this were ever you want to test

//examples

Element.onclick = function(){
  console.log("clicked");
}

Element.onkeyup = function(){
 console.log("keyup detection");
}

window.onload = function(){
  console.log("page loaded");
 }
```

Also to catch error by line you can use

```
 try{

  var invalid = "hello world';//<===== here is invalid string

}catch(e){

  console.log(e.stack);//catched error details (line, file, error)

}
```

> is it possible see the code for resize the text when i am resizing the that text ?

Example to detect button click, focus and range change

[***Check Fiddle***](https://jsfiddle.net/xogzvsjf/3/)

Comment: Sorry , i didn't understand why you give the code ? please read my question .

Comment: why you write the code ? I am not asking the code .

Comment: it's an example to test `console.log` for your code **you HAVE posted**  :)

Comment: I know how to inspect element, change style and other things . But here i am asking to know how to detect the javascript code or function for the current event.Hi, it's not about console .log function . I know this already . I am asking that how to know which function is working when i click the close button , how can i see that code in browser . Here i write the code , i understand where the code is . What about if some other write the code and i am looking browser for detecting what code and what event is running